# Play Application doesn't work well despite the initial state

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.2

Before my question, actually this is the first question on stackoverflow.
So, I might have some wrong points and if I have please point out for me.

My playFramework version is play2.2.1 and IntelliJ IDEA is 2016.2.5.
I already picked up Scala as a plugin and I could be able to select Play2.x on project selection page.
First, I choose Play2.x with Java selected when creating a new project.
And then I gave the project appropriate name and PlayApplication built.
After that, I tried to command "play run", but didn't work well in spite of no editing.

```
[info] p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: /0.0.0.0:9000
    at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:132)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer$$anonfun$1.apply(NettyServer.scala:129)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.core.server.NettyServer.<init>(NettyServer.scala:129)
    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:200)
    at play.core.server.NettyServerProvider.createServer(NettyServer.scala:199)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:208)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1.apply(DevServerStart.scala:61)
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDev(DevServerStart.scala:60)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart$.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala:50)
    at play.core.server.DevServerStart.mainDevHttpMode(DevServerStart.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at play.runsupport.Reloader$.startDevMode(Reloader.scala:207)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.devModeServer$lzycompute$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.play$sbt$run$PlayRun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$anonfun$$devModeServer$1(PlayRun.scala:73)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:99)
    at play.sbt.run.PlayRun$$anonfun$playRunTask$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(PlayRun.scala:52)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss$RegisterTask.run(NioServerBoss.java:193)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.processTaskQueue(AbstractNioSelector.java:391)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:315)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerBoss.run(NioServerBoss.java:42)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last compile:run' for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 2016/10/22 10:33:57

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to google things related to my question, but I couldn't find.
Everyone gave their playapplication any edit.
What should I do?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following command

```
activator "~run 8085"
```

you can use any port which is currently not in use.